# PPT2010 insert a imge can't get the original filename

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In MS-Powerpoint 2010, insert an image which has a name `ABC.gif`.

When I use the code to read the `.pptx` file, I can't get the original image's file name which should be `ABC.gif`, but instead I get "`Image1.gif`.

Can someone tell me how can I get the original image's fileName `ABC.gif`.

Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`, for the code operate.

Comment: Siddharth has explained how to get the name of a linked image.  PowerPoint doesn't retain the names of embedded images, though, so if that's what you have, ie, its .Type = msoPicture rather than msoLinkedPicture, you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are using VB.Net or C# so I will explain it using VBA code. You can easily adapt it to your code.

To get the filename you have to ensure that you do not just "**Insert**" the image but "**Insert And Link**" See the below screenshot.

[image]

Remember MS-PP will rename the picture to "*Picture 1, Picture 2*" etc in this case **as well** but then you can always use `LinkFormat.SourceFullName` to get the full **Filename + Path**. And once you have that, you can easily retrieve the file name.

See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim img As Shape

    For Each img In ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes
        '~~> Type is 11 when you insert and link an image
        If img.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
            Debug.Print img.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
            Debug.Print img.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks.By your method,I can get the original filename.